# in Xcode 15 I am not able to get a result of viewcontroller name in search .storyboard files

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode15

[image: Xcode 14]

**Xcode 14 ======================**

[image]

**Xcode 15 ======================**

**Previously the storyboard was also listed here but in Xcode 15 it's was not.**

Comment: I checked it, I have it in XCode 15. I think the problem has another reason.

Comment: I had the same issue in Xcode 15, it was fixed by restarting Xcode :)

Comment: I have the same issue. Restarting Xcode doesn't help. It's annoying, I have to use github to search things in the repo.

Answer (score 3):

Just removing the derived data worked for me :)

Comment: It works.
1) Close Xcode
2) Delete derived data.
3) Open Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's an indexing issue and I think I found a solution. You can rename your main folder in your project (or those folders containing storyboards), which will trigger re-indexing. Wait until it's done and then revert the changes.

After that, the search worked for me again.